# How could i fix the Illegal state Exception and the onClick() Method

Tags: android, onclick, google-maps-android-api-2, illegalstateexception, currentlocation

i have two errors on my map app. First iam trying to develop the button that show the Current location on the map,when i run the application,it's shows that the Current location is not availabale despite that the code is right.Second when i want to search the location and i Click on the Button Go the app STOPs. this is the code:

MainActiviy.java:

```
package com.example.gmapsapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
  GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
  GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9002;
    GoogleMap mMap;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final double SEATTLE_LAT = 47.60621,
    SEATTLE_LNG =-122.33207, 
    SYDNEY_LAT = -33.867487,
    SYDNEY_LNG = 151.20699, 
    NEWYORK_LAT = 40.714353, 
    NEWYORK_LNG = -74.005973;
    private static final float DEFAULTZOOM = 15;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String LOGTAG = "Maps";

    LocationClient mLocationClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (servicesOK()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

            if (initMap()) {
//              mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
                mLocationClient.connect();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Map not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean servicesOK() {
        int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to Google Play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean initMap() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag =
                    (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mMap = mapFrag.getMap();
        }
        return (mMap != null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
    }

    private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng,
            float zoom) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
    }

    public void geoLocate(View v) throws IOException {
        hideSoftKeyboard(v);

        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String location = et.getText().toString();

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        Address add = list.get(0);
        String locality = add.getLocality();
        Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        double lat = add.getLatitude();
        double lng = add.getLongitude();

        gotoLocation(lat, lng, DEFAULTZOOM);

    }

    private void hideSoftKeyboard(View v) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.mapTypeNone:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeNormal:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeSatellite:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeTerrain:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeHybrid:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            break;
        case R.id.gotoCurrentLocation:
            gotoCurrentLocation();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        MapStateManager mgr = new MapStateManager(this);
        mgr.saveMapState(mMap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MapStateManager mgr = new MapStateManager(this);
        CameraPosition position = mgr.getSavedCameraPosition();
        if (position != null) {
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position);
            mMap.moveCamera(update);
            //          This is part of the answer to the code challenge
            mMap.setMapType(mgr.getSavedMapType());
        }
    }

    protected void gotoCurrentLocation() {
        Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        if (currentLocation == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Current location isn't available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            LatLng ll = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, DEFAULTZOOM);
            mMap.animateCamera(update);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected to location service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

acitivity_map.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="Location:"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="151dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:onClick="geoLocate"
            android:text="Go" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gmapsapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.gmapsapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gmapsapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gmapsapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxx" />
         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

the Errors:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION:main
Process: com.example.gmapsapp, PID :1635
java.lang.IllegalStateException:Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
at android.vie.View.performClick(View.java.4438)
at android.view$PerformClick.run(View.java.18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThead.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygo tenit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.nativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTragetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
Caused by: java.io.IOException :Service not Available
at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:178)
at com.example.gmapsapp.MainActivity.geoLocate(MainActivity.java:1)
...14more
Sending signal. PID: 1635 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.com :) , could you post the entire error message displayed into your logcat, lines described as "Caused by"-

Comment: Hey.thank you the only lines that contains Caused by are :Causedby:java.lang.reflect.Method.InvocationTragetException 
Causedby:java.io.IOException:Service not available

Comment: I removed your API key, please be careful next time before posting such sensitive information

Comment: @user3573694 please post full logcat

Comment: im so sorry i forgot to delete it.Thank you so much!

Comment: this is the full logCat

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException :Service not Available
```

Restart your device!

**[4.1.1 Geocoder throwing exception: IOException: Service not Available](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009)**